# Adding *.vue files support to the Shopware 6 Storefront (Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-loader')

Tags: vue.js, webpack, twig, shopware6, vue-loader

I want to create mini Vue app embedded in the Shopware 6 storefront (inside TWIG ecosystem). So far I have this:

**MyPluginTheme\src\Resources\app\storefront\build\webpack.config.js**

```js
const { join, resolve } = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

console.log('VueLoaderPlugin', VueLoaderPlugin);

module.exports = (env) => {
    return {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new VueLoaderPlugin()
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@hello-world-npm': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'hello-world-npm')),
                "@vue/compiler-core": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/compiler-core')),
                "@vue/reactivity": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/reactivity')),
                "@vue/compiler-sfc": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/compiler-sfc')),
                "@vue/server-renderer": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/server-renderer')),
                "@vue/compiler-dom": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/compiler-dom')),
                "@vue/shared": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/shared')),
                "@vue/runtime-dom": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/runtime-dom')),
                "@vue/runtime-core": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/runtime-core')),
                // 'vue-loader': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue-loader')),
                '@vue': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js')),
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**MyPluginTheme\src\Resources\app\storefront\src\main.js**

```js
import { createApp, ref } from '@vue';

createApp({
    setup() {
        const count = ref(0);

        const increment = () => {
            console.log('increment from main.js', count.value);
            count.value++;
        }

        return { count, increment }
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

**Some *.twig file in my shop**

```html
<div id="app" style="background-color: yellow; padding: 8px;">
    {% verbatim %}
        <h1>-{{ count }}-</h1>
        <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
    {% endverbatim %}
</div>
```

Until this point everything works fine and my mini app works:

[image]

The issue is when I want to move my code to `*.vue` file. For this purpose I used `vue-loader` but I cannot make it working:

**MyPluginTheme\src\Resources\app\storefront\src\main.js**

```js
// ...
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue';

console.log('HelloWorld', HelloWorld);
// ...
```

Output of the build:

```
> NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js

VueLoaderPlugin [class VueLoaderPlugin] { NS: 'vue-loader' }
ℹ Compiling Shopware 6 Storefront
✔ Shopware 6 Storefront: Compiled with some errors in 6.40s
   202 modules

ERROR in /var/www/html/custom/static-plugins/MyPluginTheme/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-loader' in '/var/www/html/custom/static-plugins/MyPluginTheme/src/Resources/app/storefront/src'
```

I tried to create aliases for `vue-loader` in `webpack.config.js` but nothing works

---

UPDATE: 2022.12.28 09:28

@dneustadt found the solution! Alias for loaders should go to dedicated `resolveLoader` field in the confing not just `resolve`. Here is my **working** final `webpack.config.js` for copy pasting.

NOTE Pinia is transpiling but still not fully working, I have some error on defining the store but everything else works like a harm!

```js
const { join, resolve } = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    use: ['vue-loader'],
                },
                {
                    // https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/675
                    test: /\.mjs$/,
                    include: /node_modules/,
                    type: "javascript/auto"
                }
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new VueLoaderPlugin()
        ],
        resolveLoader: {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889165/adding-vue-files-support-to-the-shopware-6-storefront-module-not-found-error
            alias: {
                'vue-loader': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue-loader')),
            },
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@vue/compiler-dom": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/compiler-dom')),
                "@vue/compiler-core": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/compiler-core')),
                "@vue/runtime-dom": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/runtime-dom')),
                "@vue/runtime-core": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/runtime-core')),
                "@vue/shared": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/shared')),
                "@vue/reactivity": resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/reactivity')),
                '@vue/devtools-api': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@vue/devtools-api')),
                'vue-demi': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue-demi')),
                'pinia': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'pinia')),
                'vue': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js')),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory serves me right this is an issue where the loader cannot be resolved, as it is expected to be a regular dependency, not outside of the main `node_modules` directory. This doesn't change even if an alias of the same name is resolved.

In that case loaders have to be resolved separately.

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: ['vue-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
      'vue-loader': resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue-loader')),
    },
  },
}
```

If that still fails you could try to change the root for loaders.

```js
resolveLoader: {
    root: resolve(join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')),
}
```

Comment: Yes, `resolveLoader` was the solution! Thanks man! BTW `root` field doesn't exist in the Webpack 4 config.